# Очень сильно проседаю по памяти при записи byte[] в XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

пытаюсь прочитать xslx фаил и сделать в нём изменения. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему преобразование байтов в Workbook такое дорогое по памяти? почему то 9мб занимает 1.5г оперативы?
Хотя если мы взяли 900к pojo объектов и начинаем их записывать в тот же самый формат экселя и далее сохраняю в фаил, то по памяти занимает 200-300мб, как так?) Что я не так делаю?

```
private SXSSFWorkbook convertToWorkbook(byte[] content) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(bin);
        bin.reset();
        bin.close();
        workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb, 100, true, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return workbook;
}
```

Comment: не думаю, что можно что то полезное сказать по представленному коду. Вы бы потыкали палкой профайлером памяти в приложение, поглядели бы, что именно занмает 1.5 гига. Может, вы этот код в цикле запускаете или ещё что.

Comment: @tym32167, visualVM показывает на -> XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(bin); начинает жрать память, когда накатываю Workbook